# Anyone who has automated the functionning of the camera of mobile. Any suggestions where I can verify the image captured by the camera?

Tags: android, image, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, appium

I have a scenario where i take a remote connection of an Android device from my Windows machine, and then i remotely switch ON the camera of the device from my Windows system after getting control of this device. (Its similar to taking control on a screen-sharing tool)
Now i have to automate this test case and find out that i can see the same stuff on my Windows system, which the camera of the device is showing on the mobile screen.

Comment: The idea could be to capture the images both a screenshot from your Windows machine and a picture from your Mobile Camera and move them to a directory accessible to both these devices. Perform an ImageComparison thereafter.

Comment: Thanks! Will try implemented something like this.

Comment: There is a change in the requirement, could you help me with some ideas for the same.As a android user, I will be able to upload a file to the windows machine (through my application to be tested).How can I compare these two images. The actual image is in the gallery of my phone and expected is stored in the windows system. How can these two images be compared.

Comment: **move them to a directory accessible to both these devices** You can try and use adb to pull the images from your SDCard onto your Windows machine. Once both of these are in the same directory, you can make a comparison.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!

Comment: Welcome. Btw, is that all you needed?

Comment: Hey thanks, I have a similar scenario, where there are 2 windows machines involved ( so instead of an android device, now i upload a file to another windows machine). So going by the point you gave me i.e " move them to a directory accessible to both the devices" can you suggest me how do I move the file from on windows machine to another.

Comment: Or is there any way to remotely read files or something similar ? And Thanks for your quick responses , it saved me a lot!

Comment: there are plenty of ways to access images from one windows machine to another, I am sure you would find them over the Internet.

Comment: Sure will search on the lines you mentioned. Thanks again.